# Intersection Points of Diagonals of a Convex Polygon

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, euclidean-geometry

It has been shown here [http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ngon.pdf](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/ngon.pdf) that the greatest number of diagonals intersecting at a given point in the interior of a regular $n$-gon (other than the center point) is

$\begin{cases}
2&\text{if $n$ is odd}\\
3&\text{if $n$ is even but not divisible by $6$}\\
5&\text{if $n$ is divisible by $6$ but not by $30$}\\
7&\text{if $n$ is divisible by $30$.}
\end{cases}$

However, I am dealing with a convex polygon with all of its vertices on a circle, but this polygon is not necessarily regular - however, every point on it has an antipodal point with respect to the center of the circle i.e. there is central symmetry involved. In this new setting, I am specifically looking for a set of points such that every diameter includes two antipodal (i.e. centrally symmetric) points in the interior of the polygon that have a greater number of diagonals intersecting than the quantity above. Do these types of configurations of points exist? My intuition is telling me that they don't, but I am struggling to prove this.

Comment: I might understand the setting wrong, but can‘t you just take 2k points in regular position, all of whose diagonals intersect in some point p, place this inside your circle such that p is not at the center, project the 2k points outwards from p such that they lie on the circle, and then mirror the whole configuration at the center? This way you would get 4k pairwise antipodal points on a circle such that some k diagonals intersect in a common point.

Comment: @polygonlink1, It seems to me that  Patrick Schnider is absolutely right.